# python exifread sort images on linux and mac, doesn't work on windows

Tags: python

I practice python and wrote script which sorts my photos based on date of their creation, it's done by exifread package. I tested it on mac os and linux and it works flawless, however on windows first I got error that directory can't be named for example "2016:06" because of semicolon so I changed it a bit to be "2016-06", but script still shows error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
    File "imageSorter.py", line 25, in <module>
    sortPhotos()   
    File "imageSorter.py", line 22, in sortPhotos
    shutil.move((input_dir + name), (output_dir + name))
    File "C:\Python27\lib\shutil.py", line 326 in move
    os.unlink(src) 
    WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot used by another process: './landscape.jpg'
```

My code is like this:

```
def sortPhotos():
    input_dir = './'

    for name in os.listdir(input_dir):
        if name.endswith('.jpg'):
            f = open(name, 'rb')
            tags = exifread.process_file(f)
            for tag in tags.keys():
                if tag in ('Image DateTime'):
                    checked_dir_year = str(tags[tag])[0:4]
                    checked_dir_month = str(tags[tag])[5:7]
                    checked_dir_no_semicolor = checked_dir_year + '-' + checked_dir_month
                    checked_dir = str(tags[tag])[0:7]
                    if not os.path.exists(checked_dir_no_semicolor):
                        os.mkdir(checked_dir_no_semicolor)
                    if checked_dir in str(tags[tag]):
                        output_dir = './' + checked_dir_no_semicolor + '/'
                        shutil.move((input_dir + name), (output_dir + name))
```

Comment: check if any program use or open that jpg file

Comment: don't think so as I open windows virtual box, copied script and 3 jpg files, installed python and launched the script, no any other program would have a chance to use these jpg files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, before moving a file, you must close it. Or, you will see the above error message.

you must make : `f.close` before the `move` command